# PostgreSQL - group by distinct pairs of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have something like a netflow table and would like to group it in such a way that it groups it by (src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port) where the values could be swapped between the src and dst fields.

| src_ip | src_port | dst_ip | dst_port | bytes_sent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 192.168.10.5 | 321 | 111 |
| 192.168.10.5 | 321 | 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 222 |
| 10.0.0.5 | 50 | 172.0.0.5 | 55 | 500 |
| 172.0.0.5 | 55 | 10.0.0.5 | 50 | 300 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 192.168.10.5 | 321 | 1000 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 192.168.10.5 | 20 | 999 |

I would like to have the following result from this table:

| src_ip | src_port | dst_ip | dst_port | bytes_sent | bytes_recv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 192.168.10.5 | 321 | 1111 | 222 |
| 10.0.0.5 | 50 | 172.0.0.5 | 55 | 500 | 300 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 192.168.10.5 | 20 | 999 | 0 |

Basically, trying to capture the traffic going both ways in a single row. So something like grouping by (src_ip, src_port) and (dst_ip, dst_port) where those values could be inverted. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a self join.

Comment: How do you know 192.168.1.1 made a call to 192.168.10.5 and not the other way? I think without more conditions, every implementation will return 4 records. What needs to be done in case multiple records exist with the same combination of src_ip and dest_ip?

Comment: I'm not so concerned about getting the direction correct here - that is a good insight though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to decide which IP, port and direction you must have a rule who you consider sender and who receiver in your aggregated result. Let's make the lesser IP the source and the greater IP the destination. Then it's just about the same `CASE` expression again and again to decide which original column to put in which result column. Once this is done, aggregate your data.

```
with 
  data as
  (
    select
      case when src_ip < dst_ip then  src_ip      else  dst_ip      end as source_ip,
      case when src_ip < dst_ip then  dst_ip      else  src_ip      end as dest_ip,
      case when src_ip < dst_ip then  src_port    else  dst_port    end as source_port,
      case when src_ip < dst_ip then  dst_port    else  src_port    end as dest_port,
      case when src_ip < dst_ip then  bytes_sent  else  0           end as sent,
      case when src_ip < dst_ip then  0           else  bytes_sent  end as received
    from mytable
  )
select
  source_ip, source_port, dest_ip, dest_port,
  sum(sent) as bytes_sent,
  sum(received) as bytes_received
from data
group by source_ip, source_port, dest_ip, dest_port
order by source_ip, source_port, dest_ip, dest_port;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the smallest IP is the source IP, and the largest is the destination IP.

You can use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions to ensures that for each combination of the smallest and largest IP addresses, one entry will be selected :

```
with cte as (
  select least(src_ip, dst_ip) as smallestIP, greatest(src_ip, dst_ip) as largestIP
  from mytable src
  group by least(src_ip, dst_ip), greatest(src_ip, dst_ip)
),
routes as (
  select distinct src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port 
  from (
    select src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port 
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on t.src_ip = c.smallestIP
    union all
    select dst_ip as src_ip, dst_port as src_port, src_ip as dst_ip, src_port as dst_port
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on t.dst_ip = c.smallestIP
  ) as s
)
select r.src_ip, r.src_port, r.dst_ip, r.dst_port,
       sum(case when r.src_ip = t.src_ip and r.src_port = t.src_port
                     and r.dst_ip = t.dst_ip and r.dst_port = t.dst_port
                then bytes_sent else 0 end ) as bytes_sent,
       sum(case when r.src_ip = t.dst_ip and r.src_port = t.dst_port
                     and r.dst_ip = t.src_ip and r.dst_port = t.src_port
                then bytes_sent else 0 end ) as bytes_recv
from routes r
inner join mytable t on (
                        r.src_ip = t.src_ip and r.src_port = t.src_port
                        and r.dst_ip = t.dst_ip and r.dst_port = t.dst_port)
                      or (
                        r.src_ip = t.dst_ip and r.src_port = t.dst_port
                        and r.dst_ip = t.src_ip and r.dst_port = t.src_port
                      )
group by r.src_ip, r.src_port, r.dst_ip, r.dst_port
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OFUpnbxq)

Comment: I slightly updated my question example: what if there are multiple rows where the (src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port) combos that we want to group can be on either side?

Comment: Could you check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-`join`:

```
with cte as (
   select row_number() over (order by greatest(n.src_ip, n.dst_ip)) r, n.src_ip, n.src_port, n.dst_ip, n.dst_port, min(n.bytes_sent) bytes_sent from netflow n
   group by n.src_ip, n.src_port, n.dst_ip, n.dst_port
)
select n.src_ip, n.src_port, n.dst_ip, n.dst_port, n.bytes_sent, 
   coalesce(n1.bytes_sent, 0) bytes_recieved
from cte n left join cte n1 on n1.src_port = n.dst_port
where not exists (select 1 from cte n2 where n2.r < n.r and n2.dst_port = n.src_port)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cb6E_zA4)

Comment: I slightly updated my question example: what if there are multiple rows where the (src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port) combos that we want to group can be on either side?

Comment: @Tesla Please see my recent edit

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to be working correctly. The bytes_recv count isn't right, and if I add a similar IP talking to a different port, it's not grouping them correctly. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/uonmF4N2

Comment: @Tesla Please post your desired output from that sample. Also, you need to clarify 1. why `300` and `500` appear to be summed to `800` while `222` remains the same, 2. your grouping criteria, and 3. the ordering of record entries to make the join associations

Comment: Apologies - the 800 was a typo. I just updated it to be the correct 300. The desired output is now correct in the topic description.

Comment: @Tesla Thank you for the clarification, please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output by using a combination of the following statements GROUP BY, CASE and also SUM functions to aggregate your function

The following query can be done as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN src_ip ELSE dst_ip END AS src_ip,
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN src_port ELSE dst_port END AS src_port,
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN dst_ip ELSE src_ip END AS dst_ip,
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN dst_port ELSE src_port END AS dst_port,
    SUM(CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN bytes_sent ELSE 0 END) AS bytes_sent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN 0 ELSE bytes_sent END) AS bytes_recv
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN src_ip ELSE dst_ip END,
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN src_port ELSE dst_port END,
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN dst_ip ELSE src_ip END,
    CASE WHEN src_ip < dst_ip THEN dst_port ELSE src_port END;
```

The CASE statement above will determine the order of src and dst values based on their lexical order to ensure that the grouping is consistent for both directions.While the SUM and CASE statements are used to aggregate the bytes_sent values for the different directions (forward and reverse) separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to [`least()`, `greatest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) and [aggregate `filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES). [Demo@db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/BpBo1vbQ)

```
select least(   src_ip,   dst_ip  ) AS src_ip,
       least(   src_port, dst_port) AS src_port,
       greatest(src_ip,   dst_ip  ) AS dst_ip,
       greatest(src_port, dst_port) AS dst_port,
       coalesce( sum(bytes_sent)filter(where src_ip=least(src_ip,dst_ip))
                ,0) AS bytes_sent,
       coalesce( sum(bytes_sent)filter(where dst_ip=least(src_ip,dst_ip))
                ,0) AS bytes_recv
from netflow group by 1,2,3,4;
```

| src_ip | src_port | dst_ip | dst_port | bytes_sent | bytes_recv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.0.0.5 | 50 | 172.0.0.5 | 55 | 500 | 300 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 20 | 192.168.10.5 | 123 | 999 | 0 |
| 192.168.1.1 | 123 | 192.168.10.5 | 321 | 1111 | 222 |

If you prefer `null` wherever there's no traffic, you can ditch [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) that's swapping it for `0`.